# How to merely change content in html and keep all tags unchanged

Tags: python, html

How to change some words in html but save all tags and markup without changes?
For example: change "doors" to "cars" and "Any" to "Every"

```python
tf = open(html_file)
text = tf.read()
tws = text.split( )
```

**Original text is:**

```
the doors.</p>
<p>“Any man
```

**The result should be:**

```
the cars.</p>
<p>“Every man
```

**it parses like this:**

```
the
doors.</p>
<p>“Any
man
```

**This is better:**

```
the
doors.
</p>
<p>
“Any
man
```

I think, the best way is to separate by words:

```
the
doors
.
</p>
<p>
“
Any
man
```

Comment: Have you seen [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)?

Comment: Whatever you do [don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) use regex !!!!

Comment: HTMLParser - ok, how can I restore markup after changes?

Comment: HTMLParser - there is "get_starttag_text", but there is no "get_endtag_text".. Why? )

Comment: `open(html_file).read().replace('doors','cars').replace('Any','Every')`

Comment: Jonas Byström - Thank you for you answer. I need replace all forms of word (..ed, ..ing, ..s, .. ies etc.) I use singularize(). So on, I do it in the loop compare singularize(word_i_neen_to_cange) and singularize(word_from_text_html), for this I need parse html by words. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML into a tree, traverse the tree, for every text node, replace the words within.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString
import re

replace_dict = {'doors':'cars', 'any':'every'}

def replace_words(s):
        global replace_dict
        words = re.compile("([,\.;\s]\s*)").split(s)
        print words
        new_words = [replace_dict[word] if word in replace_dict else word for word in words]
        return ''.join(new_words)

def traverse(soup):
        for section in soup.contents:
                if isinstance(section, NavigableString):
                        print "Find a text string:"+ str(section)
                        newstr = replace_words(str(section.string))
                        print "New string:"+ newstr
                        soup.string.replace_with(newstr)
                else:
                        traverse(section)

html = "<html><body><a>Open doors.</a><div>any element should be replaced.</div></body></html>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

traverse(soup)

print soup

>>> <html><body><a>Open cars.</a><div>every element should be replaced.</div></body></html>
```

The method replace_words only works with simple sentences with period/comma/semicolon. You can write a more robust tokenizer for splitting the words, or use something like `tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)` in nltk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How to "replace the words within"?

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 365: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: when I parse, some words contain special symbols like that: u'\u201cI', u' ', u'don\u2019t', u' ', u'want' - it is "I don't want" how to clean it for editing and save in result? Thank you!

Comment: The string is an unicode string, you can envoke .encode('utf-8') before using it.